# Time of the year

Tags: discussion

A famous Dutch writer once stated that *the majority is wrong by definition*. Although the point of view might be a bit too drastic, there *is* some truth in it. On a website like AU, one could expect a hard time, looking from that angle, since practically everything around here is "majority driven".

The contrary turns out to be the case. I can't say I always agree with the majority, but the funny thing is that for some reason, it is always *acceptable* to disagree. Partially, it could be the result of the fact that we are a minority to begin with.

I strongly believe however that the way "we" are moderated is the most important reason that things work here like they do, in a good balance of rules and being allowed to be human. Nothing wrong to mention at least once a year the effort of our moderators, and the integrity in what they do. Thanks people, hats off!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/  Please visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, as it is quite different from a forum... 
**:D :D :D** (upvoted!)

Comment: @Fabby Meta is different from the main site. You don't have to necessarily ask a question.

Comment: The sole purpose of the above canned comment was making Jacob smile... @Seth

Comment: I did tell you I'm bad at jokes right? haha -.-

Comment: @Seth I only post answers here, the questions on the other part of the site :)

Comment: @Seth: How do you answer a question and mark it as "solved" then if it's not really a question?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Questions are marked "solved" when they have an answer with a score of >=1, no checkmark needed. However, the OP can pick their favourite answer or no answer at all. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Seth: Really? I thought it was just marked as "answered"...

Comment: @Seth I just picked my favourite answer :)

Comment: Man, looking at this post I'm inclined to think AU is the friendliest SE: even on [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) which has a fairly tightly-knit and friendly community, they are *more than* strict and purely no-fluff when it comes to the Meta. Just this comment thread is making me smile

Comment: Pure Love people that's all... Well that and pizza.... Pretty sure it's pizza.... Pure Pizza people that's all...

Comment: "Hats off!" Well, not quite yet - Winter Bash is still running... _sad_trombone.mp3_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hear hear.

I second that motion.

Season's greetings.

The force be with you.

...or whatever floats your boat to describe a general kinesthetic and appreciative form of approval. :-)

Thank you wonderful people! :-D